# Wordpress administrator capabilities

Tags: wordpress

It appears something has been done to my wordpress installation. The "administrator" role appears to not have access to the admin panel but another role does have access to some menu items. Among the menu items I do not have access to is the "plugins" menu. I am not able to disable the plugins but I can "break" them by renaming the folder (which I have done for all plugins)

Since I have renamed all the plugin folders, I assume it is not a plugin that is controlling it. Is there somewhere else I can look?

I assume `remove_menu_page()` has been used but not sure where? If it was done by an old plugin do I have to add the menu back in or should disabling the code do the trick?

I am just stumped as to where the code is residing.

Comment: Did you also rename the top level plugins folder? (and create a blank replacement).  There may be a must-use plugin sitting at the top level.

Comment: It could also be some code sitting in theme functions.php.  You could try switching to another theme temporarily.

Comment: Capabilities are adding by wp in the code, not stored in the DB (just role is stored in the wp user meta).  So once you have cleaned up code, & if your user-ids wp_capabilities user-meta still has 'administrator' in the serialised array, then hopefully cleaned code will sort it.  Try also ftp'ing up clean wp code.

Comment: @anmari I have tried renaming the "plugins" directory and replacing with a blank directory. How can I switch the theme when I don't have access to the admin panel?

Comment: Good Point!   I trust you have access to your DB via control panel & phpmyadmin - the current theme is stored in options table:   

option name: current_theme  
option_value: Twenty Seventeen.  

And while you there, check your user-meta capabilities record just in case there's some clever 'mislabelling' going on.

Comment: Maybe check the wp user level too, just in case https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-tutorial/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-fix/   and also maybe try DB repair  in case it's got bit corrupted.

Comment: Before making any further modifications check the timestamps of the files to see which ones might have been modified during the time the issues started. Also this is probably a good lesson to always keep backups.

Comment: Also you might want to check in DB for 'invisible' admin users. https://hackrepair.com/articles/wordpress/delete-invisible-wordpress-admin

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick...

```
if ( !function_exists( 'populate_roles' ) ) {
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/schema.php' );
}

populate_roles();
```